# Does Winamp include video or audio encoders?

Tags: video, audio, media, encoding, winamp

Does Winamp have an audio/video encoder? I would really enjoy that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Winamp does feature an audio converter

[image: built-in]

but doesn't have a video encoder.

Comment: Thats sad to hear

Answer (score 0):

[WinAmp Encoding Plugins](http://www.winamp.com/plugins/encoding/12)

[Ogg-Vorbis encoder v1-1 - Encoder to convert CD tracks to Ogg-Vorbis 1.1 files using the Winamp 5 built-in CD ripper](http://www.winamp.com/plugin/ogg-vorbis-encoder-v1-1/143936)